# Message queue architecture + database

Tags: database, architecture, message-queue

Is this a good message queue architecture?

- *application* stores a message into database table
- *publisher* (async) reads message from database and publishes it into a message broker
- *consumer* (async) gets message from message broker, processes it and updates database table (field consumed_at)

Database controls whether a message is pending, or already processed.

Is the database 'control' necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your requirements are:

- Asynchronous processing of data
- Transactional consistency (to prevent lost data and/or duplicate processing)

The proposed architecture is quite complex without achieving consistency.

Investigate two options:

1. **Database in control, no message broker**: In the proposed architecture, the role of the publisher is not clear. Why can't the publisher and the consumer be merged into one, thereby getting rid of the message broker? The advantage would be: transactional consistency and less components.
2. **Database and message broker integration**: If an application bridges between database adn message broker, it's difficult to achieve transactional consistency. You can lose data if the transaction commits but the message broker connection fails, or if you send a message to the broker but the transaction cannot be committed. Therefore, it needs to be solved at the middleware leve. Several database and message broker combinations offer a direct integration with transactional consistency: either both the database data and the message are persisted, or both are rolled back/discarded. Again, there wouldn't be any need for the publisher. Depending on the integration, the initial application would need to publish a message to the broker (possibly with the help of a database trigger).

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is *essentially* a system like [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) or [Apache Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/), distributed pub-sub messaging system. Instead of *mimic* those system so so, it is better to use one of them. Relational databases is better designed for working with *sets* than with *queues*.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for such architecture would be a need to update application state in database and publish a message in a transaction. Transactional publish might be very useful in some situations.

Just publishing messages to a database to pick them up later and republish into a message broker adds complexity without any real benefit. Either use only database or queue to deliver messages.

Comment: How would you control whether a message has already been processed without a repository?

Comment: Messaging system supports acking messages to avoid new processing. But even in the case of DB only solution it is not really possible to ensure no double processing. For example it would be possible to process the message and then fail to record that fact into DB. Then the message will be redelivered and double processed.